# How can I interpret this object? Is it a 1-form?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, differential-forms, line-integrals

**THE PROBLEM**

I am dealing with the following object:

$$I = \displaystyle\int_C f(x,y)\,dxdy,$$

where $C$ is a curve on the Cartesian plane and $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is any Riemann integrable function in a neighbourhood of $C$. It seems to me that this object must be interpreted as the integral over the curve $C$ of a rank two, symmetric linear form. There is no other way to interpret this object: it is not a line integral of $f(x,y)$, nor a two variable integral over a two-dimensional domain of the plane.
If what I am saying makes sense (hope someone could confirm or refute what I have previously said), I would expect that the object $I$ should be a 1-form.

Now, suppose the curve $C$ could be parametrized by some parameter $\theta$, i.e.,

$$C:\;\;\;\gamma(\theta) = (x(\theta),y(\theta)),\hskip1cm \theta\in[a,b]\subset\mathbb R,$$

Am I right if I write $I$ as follows?

$$I = \displaystyle\int_a^b f(x(\theta),y(\theta))\,x'\,y'\,d\theta\,d\theta,$$

where $x'$ and $y'$ are the first derivatives of the components of $\gamma$.
I know, it seems a little bit odd but I think it is natural in the context of symmetric rank two tensors where an object like $d\theta\,d\theta$ is written via the tensor product as $d\theta\otimes d\theta$.

Now, if fortunately what I have said makes sense and is correct, how can I compute the integration if I know the function $f(x,y)$? In other words, what theorem or concept I have to invoke in order to perform the integral

$$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x(\theta),y(\theta))\,x'\,y'\,d\theta\otimes d\theta,$$

and obtain as a result the explicit 1-form I have supposed at the beginning?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1: Answering Ted Shifrin**

The precise problem can be found on page 129 of "The Method of Moments in Electromagnetics" of W.C.Gibson (third edition). I write below the equation which made me formulate the question in this post. This is

$${\omega\mu \over 4}\int_C {\bf J}({\bf\rho}') H_0^{(2)}(k|{\bf\rho}-{\bf \rho}|)d{\bf \rho}'={\bf E}^{i}({\bf \rho}).$$

In this equation, $\omega, \mu$ and $k$ are electrodynamical parameters, $H^{(2)}_0$ is an Hankel function of the second kind, $\bf J$ and $\bf E$ are the current density and the incident electric field respectively (they are vectors, but each component can be treated separately). The integration variable is $\rho' = (x',y')$ as one can find at page 137 of the above text book in Eq. (6.77) (hence a vector of the Cartesian plane). Finally, the curve $C$ is a "contour of arbitrary shape" paraphrasing Gibson. Everything is made clear by just looking at the FIGURE 6.6 at page 138 of the book in question: the contour is a curve of ${\mathbb R}^2$ while the integration variable $\rho'$ is a vector of the same plane.

How would you interpret the equation above?

Comment: This just makes no sense. You cannot integrate a symmetric $2$-tensor over a curve. Where did you find this and what is the *precise* statement? If you have a fiber bundle $X\to Y$ with (oriented) fibers $F$ of dimension $k$, then you can integrate an $r$-form on $X$ over the fiber and end up with a $(r-k)$-form on $Y$. But you are not in this situation.

Comment: Hi Ted! Thanks for answering. I have just added some more info in the principal body of the post. Regards.

Comment: Almost certainly $d\rho'$ does not represent $dx' \, dy'$ (which would be an area form). I imagine that this is a path integration, and $d\rho'$ represents an infinitesmal element of a parameterization of the curve $C$. But none of us have the book so we can't tell you. I suggest flipping through the pages of the book fo find where the author explains his notation for path integration. Or look up path integration in a calculus book to see if it makes sense.

Comment: I do not have access to the book, but as this stands it makes no sense. For starters, there’s an $i$th component on the RHS. I would need to see the text to determine whether this is an error of interpretation an actual error. I suspect this comes from Maxwell’s equations and an application of Stokes’s Theorem, so it really is a surface integral over a region bounded by $C$, but then we recover the circulation of $\mathbf E$, not a pointwise value. Or maybe he’s using Green’s functions to solve a PDE.

Comment: The $i$ apex indicated just "incident field". The equation comes from Maxwell's equations and it is called EFIE (electric field integral equation) where the unknown to be determined is the currendìt density $\bf J$. The key point here is the Green function, which is used to write down the equation (note that in it compare the Hankel function which is the 2-dimensional Green function). The EFIE is used for scattering problems by the conductor $C$.

Comment: Dear Lee Mosher, thanks for the comment. I also think I should interpret the role of $d\rho'$ better.

Comment: That's a path integral (along curve C on a 2D plane), not an area integral. If radius vector r=r(x,y) traces the path, then the line element under integral is denoted as dr. Metric tensor plays a role then, $dr=\sqrt{dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy}$

Comment: If the author is in fact using Green's functions, the integral *should* be a double integral and the $C$ is the miscue here. He's integrating over a region, not over a curve. I suspect that there are going to be lots of "physicist's sloppinesses" as you proceed through this text.

Comment: I have done a little of a research. What I found is that the same equation is often written as a path integral over the curve. At this point it seems that it must be seen as so. Lot's of "physicist's sloppinesses" indeed... Anyway, thanks all of you for your precious help!